# asp.net DataGrid Convert YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Input data is 20160902 (YYYYMMDD)

I'm trying to display this as MM/dd/yyyy in **ASP.NET Data Grid** and tried to use DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" which didn't work.

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: The best approach for formatting data in a grid control is to format the data in the datasource before binding it to the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your data field is not a date. It may be a string or an integer. You could make sure that your data is retrieved as a date and format it with `DataFormatString`:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="MyDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

If, for some reason, that option is not available, you can show your data field in a TemplateColumn of the DataGrid (replace "MyDate" in the example below by the actual name of your data field):

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("MyDate").ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Yes the input is as string. Can't we format it if the input data type is a String?

Comment: Did you try the TemplateColumn?

Comment: Nope i didn't give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal and assign value to literal in item databound  to 
`Convert.ToDateTime("source date").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`